# XSLT how to control <tr>

Tags: html, xslt, sharepoint

I am working on a listview in Sharepoint which has the following structure.

```
<Rows>
   <Row Employee='Marc1' Manager='John'/>
   <Row Employee='Marc2' Manager='John'/>
   <Row Employee='Marc3' Manager='John'/>
   <Row Employee='Marc4' Manager='John'/>
   <Row Employee='Marc5' Manager='John'/>
   <Row Employee='Marc6' Manager='Bob'/>
   <Row Employee='Marc7' Manager='Bob'/>
   <Row Employee='Marc8' Manager='Bob'/>
   ...
</Rows>
```

The idea is to print the 3 employee column in one table row. And when a different manager comes, we add a new row. It should look like this.

```
<table>
 <tr>
 <td>Marc1</td>
 <td>Marc2</td>
 <td>Marc3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Marc4</td>
 <td>Marc5</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Marc6</td>
 <td>Marc7</td>
 <td>Marc8</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Until now I have the following code, which gives me a new line after every 3rd element and also when manager is different.

```
  <xsl:template match='dsQueryResponse'>
  <table align="center">    
    <tbody>
     <xsl:apply-templates select='Rows/Row'/>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match='Row'>
    <xsl:if test="(position() =1) or (position() mod 3) = 1">
        <tr >

        </tr>
   </xsl:if>


    <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::Row[position()=1]/@Manager != @Manager"> 
        <tr>

        </tr>
    </xsl:if>

    .......
```

The only problem is that when a new line is added because of manager, count() looses its effectiveness with mod 3. Because of the change in manager it will print a new line for Marc 6 and now as condition with mod 3, fulfils for Marc 7, it will again print a new line (which I want to avoid) and table will be printed like this. Any idea how can I achieve this?

```
<table>
 <tr>
 <td>Marc1</td>
 <td>Marc2</td>
 <td>Marc3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Marc4</td>
 <td>Marc5</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Marc6</td>
 </tr>
 <td>Marc7</td>
 <td>Marc8</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT 2.0 or just XSLT 1.0? The splitting of the rows by Manager is a "grouping" problem, and this is done differently in XSLT 2.0. In XSLT 1.0 you use a technique called "Muenchian Grouping" (See http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html), but in XSLT 2.0 you can use the friendlier **xsl:for-each-group** (See http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1314)

Comment: Thanks Tim for quick response. I am using XSLT 1.0 and I will definitely look for Muenchian technique.

Comment: i was once kind of stuck with the complex xslt logic. So instead what i did is use jQuery to render it:) So i load all the information in normal format, in hidden div. Than using jquery just parse this html and restructure however you want. Way easier than xslt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need jQuery!? The following **XSLT (1.0)** generates your required output.

- group_by_manager - groups the `Row` elements by unique `@Manager`
- group_by_position - groups the (sub-grouped) `Row` elements by position (e.g. 1-3)
- print_row - prints the `Row` elements into a HTML row.

  ```
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/" name="group_by_manager">
    <table>
      <xsl:for-each select="//Rows/Row[not(@Manager=preceding::*/@Manager)]">
        <xsl:variable name="foo" select="." />
        <xsl:call-template name="group_by_pos">
          <xsl:with-param name="cells" select="//Rows/Row[@Manager=$foo/@Manager]" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="group_by_pos">
    <xsl:param name="cells" />
    <xsl:for-each select="$cells[position() mod 3 = 1]">
        <xsl:variable name="start" select="((position()-1)*3)+1" />
        <xsl:variable name="end" select="$start+2" />
        <xsl:call-template name="print_row">
          <xsl:with-param name="cells" select="$cells[position() &gt;= $start and position() &lt;= $end]" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="print_row">
    <xsl:param name="cells" />
    <tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="$cells">
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@Employee" /></td>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
  ```